# How to register an user using Facebook Login?

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk-3.1

I have an android app and a web interface for my user to interact with my system. I managed to make the user Login through Facebook LoginButton into my App and now I would like to register it on my own database.

1. Just to confirm: It is possible to use the same Facebook Application both on the Android App and on the Web, right?
2. Which user's information(s) should I store on my database so if the user Logins either on my app or my web interface, my system will be able to recognize him? I though about the facebook username, but I was told it may change...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Just to confirm: It is possible to use the same Facebook Application both on the Android App and on the Web, right?

**Right**. In the *Settings* tab you can click *Add Platform* and select the platform where you want to integrate.

> Which user's information(s) should I store on my database so if the user Logins either on my app or my web interface, my system will be able to recognize him?

The facebook unique id should be stored in the database. More specifically (considering the recent changes in the API) - [**app-scoped user id**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading/#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids) must be stored in the database. This id is unique for a user using an application. So when a user logins to the application using app/web you can recognize him with this id. You can get the user id with : `/me` API call.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much Sahil. It is a simple question I know but I couldn't find it anywhere. Thanks a lot. o/